# Re-installing Windows 7 without original recovery disk

Tags: windows-7, installation

I need to reinstall Windows 7 but I don't have the original disk that goes with the machine I do however have a different Windows 7 disk. My question is would I be able to install Windows 7 using this separate disk? I have a licence key for Windows 7 which I can use but I'm wondering if each Windows 7 disk is tied to a specific licence key?

Comment: You shouldn't have problems activating with a generic [retail disc](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft), else you can always call the automated MS activation hotline.

Answer (score 0):

some windows 7 disks work, but some have issues activating. I used a dell disk on a compaq machine and i couldn't activate windows :(

i'm assuming they are manufacturer specific?

if so i believe you can download a generic windows 7:

http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58996.iso (home premium x86)

http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58997.iso (home premium x64)

http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59183.iso (PRO x86)

http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59186.iso (PRO x64)

burn the right iso to a dvd and boot from it.

Comment: Digital River links no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe the Microsoft license agreement requires you to obtain replacement OEM disk(s) from the vendor...Unfortunately, all OEM media isn't created equal.